# data:Url php with random numbers

Tags: php

I need to write a function that returns a **date:url picture** with a random number, I’m absolutely confused, here are my attempts, tell me where to go next

```
$function = new \Twig\TwigFunction('picture', function () {

    header("Content-Type: image/png");
    $im = @imagecreate(50, 50)
    or die("Невозможно создать поток изображения");
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
    $string = rand();
    imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  $string, $text_color);
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
    $img64 = base64_encode($im);
    return $img64;

});

$twig->addFunction($function);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Comment: Could you explain more about your goal, ist the creation of a random string the problem, or the handling and delivering of the image response, ...

Comment: Doesn't imagedestroy() destroy the actual resource and therefore cannot be returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issues:

1. `header("Content-Type: image/png");` doesn't make any sense. Your function returns plain text that isn't even meant to be returned to browser as-is but injected inside HTML. Get rid of this line.
2. The `@` in `@imagecreate(50, 50)` is the [error control operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). By default it'll just hide useful error messages from you. You don't possibly want it either.
3. You define `$background_color` but never use it. You can feed it to [`imagefill()`](https://php.net/imagefill) or, if you want it black, omit it altogether.
4. [`imagepng($im)`](https://php.net/imagepng) immediately prints the image. That's bad when you want to process and return it. You can capture with e.g. [output control functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php).
5. `base64_encode($im)` triggers:

   > Warning: base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource

   You're incorrectly assuming that [`imagecreate()`](https://php.net/imagecreate) returns the final image bytes; it doesn't. It returns a resource to be passed as argument to other image functions. You don't need it for anything else. Additionally, if you didn't see the message it can mean that you haven't configured PHP to [display error messages](https://phptherightway.com/#changing-phps-error-reporting-behaviour).
6. There's no need to `imagedestroy()`. The image is local to the function, builtin garbage collector will take care.
7. Don't store the image bytes in temporary variables for no reason, that will only increase memory consumption.

So you basically need to understand that your code is not a black box and ensure that every line you write has a purpose known to you and is used as the corresponding manual page explains.

```
$im = imagecreate(50, 50)
    or die("Невозможно создать поток изображения");
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
$string = rand();
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  $string, $text_color);
ob_start();
imagepng($im);
return base64_encode(ob_get_clean());
```

Comment: yes, its works, thank you! but i added also background color